# mysql ERROR 1064 with ALTER statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `car_table` with columns car_id,VIN,color,year,make,model,price
in exactly that order, then I wanted to alter the table, so I would have COLUMN year on place SIXTH or BEFORE column price , so I used this:

```
ALTER TABLE car_table
MODIFY COLUMN year SIXTH;
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE car_table
MODIFY COLUMN year BEFORE price;
```

And I get ERROR 1064 , then I searched on stackoverflow and tried this

```
ALTER TABLE 'car_table'
MODIFY COLUMN 'year' SIXTH;
```

And I get ERROR 1064 again

Comment: `year` is the name of a MySQL function. Either change the name or wrap it in ticks.

Answer (score 1):

try as below

```
ALTER TABLE Car_table MODIFY COLUMN `year` VARCHAR(4) AFTER `model`;
```